# Haskell parse error on input

Tags: haskell, import, module

I'm new to haskell, and I'm trying to play around with some modules.
I wrote this very basic module:

```
module Cube
(
    cubeArea
) where

cubeArea :: Float -> Float
cubeArea sideSize = sideSize * sideSize * sideSize
```

in a file named "Cube.hs".
Then, I opened ghci in the cmd in the same folder the Cube.hs is.
Now, when I type `import Cube.hs`, I get this error:

> :26:8: error: parse error on input `Cube.hs'

Any idea why?

Comment: In ghci use `:l Cube.hs` to load a source file.

Comment: `import` takes a module name, not a file name

Answer (score 0):

Start `GHCi`:

- ghci `Cube.hs`
- stack ghci `Cube.hs`

While already in `GHCi`:

- `:l Cube.hs` or `:load Cube.hs`
- `:r Cube.hs` or `:reload Cube.hs`

You can see all the available types and functions by entering `:browse`.